# How to check whether the pop up dialog is already open?

Tags: mfc, parent-child

I am having a button in main dialog,if I click that,pop up dialog box will be opened.Now,I should stop creation of so many pop up dialog boxes when I click that button.So,I need to check whether the child window is opened already.Help me,how to get the handle of child window?

Comment: The pop up dialog is modeless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is something that you would want in your program but surely give it a try. May be once your work is done with the first pop up dialog box, add another button, name is "Close" in your popup box that would allow it close it and in the Event Handler for it, just type OnOK().

```
void CMyDlg::OnClose()
{
    CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

..
Hope this helps.